# Python - Understanding Zip

Tags: python, python-3.x, zip

```
def zip(*iterables):
    # zip('ABCD', 'xy') --> Ax By
    sentinel = object()
    iterators = [iter(it) for it in iterables]
    while iterators:
        result = []
        for it in iterators:
            elem = next(it, sentinel)
            if elem is sentinel:
                return
            result.append(elem)
            print(elem)
        yield tuple(result)
```

Use:

```
list(zip('abc','def'))
```

Output:

```
a
d
b
e
c
f
[('a', 'd'), ('b', 'e'), ('c', 'f')]
```

**Question:**
Why does 'd' get passed in after 'a' and not 'b'?

Comment: it merges every i'th element of each iterable passed to it.

Comment: You pair up the elements, first elements together, second elements together, etc. Why would `'d'` be added to `'b'`?

Comment: You might understand what it does better if you look at [the picture of a zipper](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zipper)

Comment: Question misunderstood I think.  My question is:  What part of the code is responsible for making 'd' come after 'a'?  Does iter() produce some object like ['a','d','b','e','c','f']?

Comment: @Robert: answer: the whole `zip` function. Your question contains pure Python implementation. You need to understand what `iter` and `next` functions do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The use of next is restricting the values accessed within `'abc'` and `'def'`.

```
iterators=[iter('abc'),iter('def')]
for it in iterators:
    print(next(it))
    print(next(it))
    print(next(it))
```

Output:

a

b

c

d

e

f

Now, if we only use next once in the for loop we will only get one element from each of the sequences; this element will then be exhausted from the iterator.  Because the first element has been exhausted we can now access the second element of each sequence in the same manner.

```
iterators=[iter('abc'),iter('def')]
for x in range(1,4):
    print('Next will access element :' +str(x))

    for it in iterators:
        print(next(it))

    print('Element %s has been exhausted\n' %(str(x)))
```

Output

```
Next will access element :1

a

d

Element 1 has been exhausted


Next will access element :2

b

e

Element 2 has been exhausted


Next will access element :3

c

f

Element 3 has been exhausted
```